# Prove that $\vert z_1-z_2\vert$ is more than or equal to $\vert z_1 \vert - \vert z_2 \vert$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that $\vert z_1 - z_2 \vert \geq \vert z_1\vert - \vert z_2 \vert$ where $z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers.
I know that you have to use the triangle inequality for say $\vert z_1+z_2 \vert \leq \vert z_1 \vert  \vert z_2 \vert$ but how would you apply it in this case?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$|z_1|=|(z_1-z_2)+z_2|$$